# WPF Ribbon ToolTip flickers

Tags: wpf, tooltip

I have a very strange behavior on my Tooltips that are associated with dropdown items.

I've posted a video because it's easier to see
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKK4i.jpg

My XAML looks something like this

```
 <RibbonGroup x:Name="PageRibbonGroup" Header="{x:Static p:Resources.Page_Ribbon_Group}" LargeImageSource="{svgc:SvgImage Source='pack://application:,,,/Resources/HomeTab/Page/page_group.svg'}">
                        <RibbonComboBox>
                            <RibbonGallery x:Name="PagesListComboboxGallery" SelectedItem="{Binding XPath=.}" MaxColumnCount="1">
                                <RibbonGalleryCategory  x:Name="PagesListComboboxGalleryCategory" ItemsSource="{Binding}"/>
                                <RibbonGallery.ToolTip>                                       
                                    <ToolTip Placement="Bottom" Content="ASDF" ToolTipService.ShowDuration="5000"/>
                                </RibbonGallery.ToolTip>
                            </RibbonGallery>
                        </RibbonComboBox>
 </RibbonGroup>
```

This happens from what I see on every tooltip that is on an Element that is in a dropdown.

I can't find a reason on why this is happening.

I've also created a repo
https://github.com/SebiCiuca/RibbonToolTipFlicker

For combobox and dropdown button you can reproduce this behavior, but for Button3 the Tooltip works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/pull/6063/files

Looks like a WPF Bug introduced in version 6.0.3, that should be fixed in .NET 6.0.5

This behavior does not reproduce in .NET 5 or .NET 6.0.2.

Comment: I'm using .NET 6.0 and I'm getting this issue.

Comment: From what I've read the fix is done, but not yet released. From git it looks like they are trying to release it in 6.0.5.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a workaround that bypasses the bug, as I am, you may be able to retarget your project to .NET 5.0. An alternative that keeps using .NET 6.0 is to publish your start-up project as self-contained deployment and configure the project with the `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` set to `6.0.2`.

This is how you can do it from within Visual Studio 2022:

1. In the menu click <kbd>Build</kbd> → <kbd>Publish Selection</kbd>.
2. Click <kbd>+ New</kbd>, select *Folder* in the wizard, click <kbd>Next</kbd> and *Folder* then <kbd>Next</kbd> again.
3. Choose a folder for the output of the publish process and click <kbd>Finish</kbd>.
4. At the bottom of the *Settings* panel for the publish profile, click *Show all settings*.
5. In the dialog select set *Deployment mode* to **Self-contained** and click <kbd>Save</kbd> button. The Publish profile should look similar the image below.

[image: Publish Selection]

6. Next, you'll need to manually edit the *.csproj* for. It's easiest to do this with a text editor such as VSCode or Notepad++ but even built-in Windows Notepad should do it.
7. Once you have the '.csproj' file open, at the following XML tag beneath the `<TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>` tag and save the project:

```
    <RuntimeFrameworkVersion>6.0.2</RuntimeFrameworkVersion>
```

8. Return to Visual Studio, click <kbd>Publish</kbd> and once complete, click the *Open folder* link.

You can now find and run the .exe file within the publish folder and it should run your application using .NET 6.0.2 instead of the current latest 6.0.3 and the tooltip bug should no longer be present. If you still see the bug and you're not sure if you've retargeted your project correctly, you can arrange to present the value of the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.FrameworkDescription` which should return the value ".NET 6.0.2" if done correctly.

Note that if you run your project from the usual `bin\Release` or `bin\Debug` directory (as would running the project from Visual Studio) it will use whatever the current release is. Only the published application will use the previous version. You'll also need to remember to republish your project whenever you make a code change if you want to test it with the .NET 6.0.2 runtime.

Once .NET 6.0.5 is released and you want to publish your application using the new version, simply reverse step 6 above by remove the `RuntimeFrameworkVersion` element from the .csproj file.