# WPF Button tooltip just pops up for a blink of an eye

Tags: wpf, xaml, tooltip

In my WPF application I have a datagrid and one of it's columns contains two buttons. The buttons should have a tooltip, which appears with a 500ms delay. Unfortunately, the Tooltip just pops up for a blink of an eye.

The button's code:

```
<Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding Path=Data.CreateSingleBrickLinkInvoiceCommand, 
                                Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}}" ToolTip="{DynamicResource create_invoice_tooltip}" 
                                       ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="500" >
                                <Image Source="/Images/download.png" />
                            </Button>
```

Comment: maybe same issue as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71574744/how-can-i-find-out-why-a-tooltip-is-closing-in-wpf) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71369182/wpf-ribbon-tooltip-flickers)?

Comment: Thank you for providing the links, looks like it is the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

try use ToolTipService.ShowDuration Attached Property

```
<Button ToolTipService.ShowDuration="500" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding Path=Data.CreateSingleBrickLinkInvoiceCommand, 
                                Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}}" ToolTip="{DynamicResource create_invoice_tooltip}" 
                                       ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="500" >
                                <Image Source="/Images/download.png" />
                            </Button>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve the problem.